# how to find index of mismatch elements in two lists with two elements variants?

Tags: python, list, zip

I have two different lists with two elements variants: 'POSITIVE' and 'NEGATIVE'. I made a list comprehension to find mismatches, but I can't return the indexes using index(), maybe I'm using the function in the wrong place. I'm trying to accomplish this keeping the list comprehension.

### Code

```py
l1 = ['POSITIVE', 'NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE', 'NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE', 'NEGATIVE',
           'POSITIVE', 
           'POSITIVE', # mismatch
           'POSITIVE', 
           'POSITIVE'] # mismatch

l2 = ['POSITIVE', 'NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE', 'NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE', 'NEGATIVE',
           'POSITIVE', 
           'NEGATIVE', # mismatch
           'POSITIVE', 
           'NEGATIVE'] # mismatch

mismatch = [i for i, j in zip(l1, l2) if i != j]

print(mismatch)
['POSITIVE', 'POSITIVE']

# expected output
[7, 9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` and `j` are iterating over the elements of the lists, not the indices. If you want to get the index, use the `enumerate` function in python:

```py
mismatch = [i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)) if a != b]
```

Here's another way using `range` instead of `enumerate` and `zip`:

```py
mismatch = [i for i in range(len(l1)) if l1[i] != l2[i]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use `enumerate()` when you want to iterate over values and indices at the same time. You don't really need `zip()` for this:

```
mismatch = [i for i,v in enumerate(l1) if v != l2[i]]
```

although `zip()` would be beneficial in cases where the lists are of different lengths. Also the filter condition can be written more clearly as shown in [@JayMody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66359981/21945).